# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript

So I have the following vbscript to updatea table on a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express instance on my local machine which works as expected:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=mycomputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Purchasing;Integrated Security=SSPI"

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Budget SET Current_Budget='2999.00' WHERE Manager_ID='8869'"
objCommand.Execute
objConnection.Close
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I change:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

to:

```
user id='user';password='password
```

it tells me I'm unable to login (using user in the form of DOMAIN\user), which is a problem because I intend to use this vbscript on an internal website, so I need to be able to specify.  Looking for any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if authentication for the server is mixed mode?

Comment: Yes, it is currently in mixed mode.